# Customer-Product Analytics

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, predictive-modeling

I am new to Data Science and I want to make Customer Product Analytics for my company(bank). I can have a data of customers, their income, daily transactions, average balance etc and what product(saving certificates etc) they have taken according to their account balance. Can i have a prediction for new customers or existing customers that what product will be suitable for them according to their average balance , income etc? Can the machine learning algorithm predict each product to a particular customer?
I got to know cluster analysis and predictive analysis can be useful for such task. But i want to recommend a particular product to a particular customer. Which algorithm can be useful? And from where I have to begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have historic data of earlier purchase by customers. Try to build any classification algo ( Decision tree/ RF) to build rule associated with customer and product. 
   Now you can suggest product to a new customer associating his properties to rules which are already created. Just goole classification algos in R/Python

Clustering ( K means/Hiearchical etc)  would be good for customer segmentation, not directly useful for prediction.

https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/2017/09/hierarchical-clustering-bottom-up.html

You can also use market Basket analysis for recommending similar products to existing customer.

https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/2016/11/recommendation-engine-market-basket.html

http://courseprojects.souravsengupta.com/cds2016/product-recommendations-a-multi-classification-problem/

Comment: Thankyou for your links, they were really helpful. I will work on it more by using these links.

Comment: @Maryam - please I am interested in learning about the outcome of this project. Thanks